# On key press of Enter, click a button in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my fiddle: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/52a7ppt2/)

There is a button called "fb-send", which has to get clicked on key press on "enter" in the input field. How to achieve this?

```
<input @keyup.enter="" placeholder="Reply here" class="fb-comment-input" />
<i class="material-icons fb-button-right fb-send">&#x21E8;</i>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my answer fiddle: [ANSWER-DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/52a7ppt2/2/)

I solved this using $refs.

```
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
  methods:{
    enterClicked(){
        alert("Enter clicked")
    },
    trigger () {
        this.$refs.sendReply.click()
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Question: How do you avoid shift+enter or ctr+enter triggering the method 'trigger()'. I want shift+enter to break line.

Answer (score 32):

You can also call method for fb_send directly on input field:

```
@keyup.enter="enterClicked()"
```

Comment: I used the enterClicked() only to detect if the icon was being clicked. So I cannot assign the method directly on key press of Enter :)

Answer (score 10):

```
<Input v-model="value1" size="large" placeholder="large size" @keyup.enter.native="search"></Input>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 10):

**14 June, 2020**

**Enter and KeyPress will work both.**

Grab the Input fields in a form like this:

```
<form v-on:keyup.enter="login">
    <input type="email" v-model="email">
    <input type="password" v-model="password">
    <button type="button" @click="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Javascript Part:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            email: null,
            password: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
           console.log("Login is working........");
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Mr. Perfectionist: well explained

Answer (score 8):

You need to call `enterClick` method inside input field like below:

```
<div id="app">
    <input @keyup.enter="enterClicked" placeholder="Reply here" class="fb-comment-input" />
    <i class="fb-send" @click="enterClicked">&#x21E8;</i>
</div>
```

---

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        methods:{
          enterClicked(){
             alert("Enter clicked")
          }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I used the enterClicked() only to detect if the icon was being clicked. So I cannot assign the method directly on key press of Enter :)

Comment: The example provided by @IncharaRaveendra is working fine... You can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/nosferatu79/52a7ppt2/3/

Answer (score 3):

Please use @keyup.enter.native=function(), this will work .

native function is a function provided by your browser/server/JavaScript

Comment: nowadays: '.native' modifier on 'v-on' directive is deprecated  vue/no-deprecated-v-on-native-modifier

Answer (score -7):

```
        $("form").keypress(function (e) {
            debugger;
            if(e.charCode == 13){
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with some explanation.

Comment: The question was for vuejs which follows MVVM pattern. jQuery is impractical for its scope