# @keyup.enter only works when tab is set to the login button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, enter

The only time my login button works is when I a direct the tab button after inputting email and password,

I want it to work anytime I press enter and I am on the Login page.

this is a vueJS application

Html template

```html
<template>
        <div class="login-page" id="login-page">
            <div class="form" id="form">
                <form class="login-form" id="login-form">
                <div class="head-login">
                <img class="teamfu-image" src="../assets/teamfu-v.png"/><h2 class="login">Login</h2>
                </div>
                <hr class="beneathBorder" color="white">
                <div>
                    <p class="text">Email:<input v-model="input.email" class="input" type="text" placeholder='e.g. johndeer@gmail.com'/></p>
                    <p class="text">Password:<input v-model="input.password" class="input" type="password" placeholder=" " /></p>
                </div>
                <button type="button" @click="login" @keyup.enter="login" > Login</button>
                <p class="message">Not a part of the team? <router-link class="reg" :to="'/register'">Register</router-link></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
</template>
```

Script

```html
<script>
import { checkUser } from "../db/storage";

export default {
    name : 'login-page',
    data() {
        return{
            input: {
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods : {
        login() {
            if(this.input.email != "" && this.input.password != "") {

                if(checkUser(this.input.email,  this.input.password) ) {

                    this.$emit("authenticated", true);
                    this.$router.replace('/dashboard');

                } else {

                alert("The username and / or password is incorrect")
                console.log("The username and / or password is incorrect");
            }
        } else {
            
            alert("A username and password must be present")
            console.log("A username and password must be present");
        }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639549/on-key-press-of-enter-click-a-button-in-vuejs/62369131#62369131 this could be your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a page-level keyup handler, you will need to apply it as high on your tree as you can:

```
<div class="login-page" @keyup.enter="login" id="login-page">
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I actually just changed my button to an input of type submit and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it would be better to use the form's [`submit` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) to invoke `login()` instead of using `click`/`keyup` handlers on the button. The `<form>` automatically emits the `submit` event when the user clicks the form's submit button, or when the user hits <kbd>ENTER</kbd> while the form is focused.

First, make it a submit-`button`, and remove the existing `click`/`keyup` handler:

```html
<!-- ❌
<button type="button" @click="login" @keyup.enter="login">Login</button>
-->
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

Then add a `submit`-handler to the form:

```html
<form @submit.prevent="login">
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/submitting-forms-in-vue-06igf?file=/src/components/LoginPage.vue)

Comment: thankyou for your answer, I actually just changed my button to an input of type submit and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I deleted this:

```
❌
<button type="button" @click="login" @keyup.enter="login" > Login</button>
```

and used this instead and it worked

```
<input type="submit" value="login" @keyup.enter="login()">
```

thank for your responses, I appreciate it